# Multiple Drop downs the item which is selected in one drop down should not be available in another drop down in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple drop downs on which I `loop` to get the values from `database` and display them into the drop down, suppose I have four drop downs each drop down contains values from 1 to 4, what I need is if user select "1" from "drop down 1" then other drop downs should not have 1 present in it, means only 1 is selected once from these four drop downs. If user select "4" from "drop down 2" then 4 will not be available in other three drop downs, How can I achieve this functionality in javascrpit?

As i have solved this in jquery i need to convert this code in Javascript

i have implemented the code in Jquery i need to convert in Javascript

```
$(function() {
    var selects = $('select').change(function() {
    $('option').prop('disabled', false).show();
    selects.each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
      if (value) {
            selects.not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').prop('disabled', true).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Which parts are causing you problems in converting? As it stands this is too broad a question.

Comment: i need the entire code to convert in Javascript as i am not expert in JS